# Create XNA sprite on the fly from an image

Tags: c#, sprite, xna-4.0

I have an image, let's says a .png, that is uploaded by the user.
This image has a fixed size, let's say 100x100.

I would like to create 4 sprites with this image.

One from (0,0) to (50,50)

Another from (50, 0) to (100, 50)

The third from (0, 50) to (50, 100)

The last from (50, 50) to (100, 100)

How can I do that with my prefered C# ?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a texture from a PNG file, use the `Texture2D.FromStream()` method ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff434103.aspx)).

To draw the different sections of the texture, use the `sourceRectangle` parameter to an overload of `SpriteBatch.Draw` that accepts it ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritebatch.draw.aspx)).

**Here's some example code:**

```
// Presumably in Update or LoadContent:
using(FileStream stream = File.OpenRead("uploaded.png"))
{
    myTexture = Texture2D.FromStream(GraphicsDevice, stream);
}

// In Draw:
spriteBatch.Begin();
spriteBatch.Draw(myTexture, new Vector2(111), new Rectangle( 0,  0, 50, 50), Color.White);
spriteBatch.Draw(myTexture, new Vector2(222), new Rectangle( 0, 50, 50, 50), Color.White);
spriteBatch.Draw(myTexture, new Vector2(333), new Rectangle(50,  0, 50, 50), Color.White);
spriteBatch.Draw(myTexture, new Vector2(444), new Rectangle(50, 50, 50, 50), Color.White);
spriteBatch.End();
```